# Input parameter 'controlId' cannot be an empty string when using validator inside formview

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have got a FormView where I have several fields. Those fields should be validated by asp.net validators, like this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="OrderDetails" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="DS_Order" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateRows="false" ClientIDMode="Static" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="EinkaufsauftragsNr" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Bind("EinkaufsauftragsNr") %>'/>
        <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="EditValidation" Display="Dynamic"
                                    ControlToValidate="EinkaufsauftragsNr" ErrorMessage="Nur Ganzzahlen erlaubt." CssClass="validator" />
        .....
    </EditItemTemplate>
</FormView>
```

But when I execute this, I get: "Input parameter 'controlId' cannot be an empty string."
When I remove the validator, the error-msg disappears as well.

After searching for this problem on the net, I thought the problem was that the control cannot be found inside the formview, so I put the clientidmode="static" there -> but that didn't solve my problem.
Do you have any other suggestions on how I could solve this one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not assign id to CompareValidator Control, You `have to assign ID to asp:CompareValidator`

**Change**

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="EditValidation" Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="EinkaufsauftragsNr" ErrorMessage="Nur Ganzzahlen erlaubt."
    CssClass="validator" />
```

**To**

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="SomeID" runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="EditValidation" Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="EinkaufsauftragsNr" ErrorMessage="Nur Ganzzahlen erlaubt."
    CssClass="validator" />
```

Comment: Thx mate, that did the trick. 

But could you elaborate why i need the id of the validator here, i have something very similar on another page and i didnt need the id there!?

Comment: This is an educated guess - the ControlToValidate could be the same value for multiple Validators so the framework needs an id to differentiate and be able to apply them independently